# Can't access $parent from ng-included controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-include

I'm pretty new to Angular and I'm trying to build an app.

I use `ng-include` to insert my view, depending on the `currentURL` variable of my main controller.
When I try to access the main controller via `$parent` from the *ng-included* file, all I get is `undefined`.

My goal is to change the `currentURL` variable to update the view.

Here is my code:

**index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl as main">
    currentURL : {{main.currentURL}}
    <div ng-include="main.currentURL"></div>

    <script src="/vendors/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/modules/login.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
angular
    .module('mcaApp', ['login'])
    .controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl);

function mainCtrl() {
    var vm = this,
        baseURL = 'views/';
    vm.currentURL = baseURL + 'login.html';
}
```

**views/login.html**

```
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl as login">
    <h1>LOGIN</h1>
</div>
```

**modules/login.js**

```
angular
    .module('login', [])
    .controller('loginCtrl', loginCtrl);

function loginCtrl() {
    var vm = this;

    console.log(vm.$parent); // undefined
}
```

Comment: you need to use `$scope.$parent` that will give you access to parent scope

Comment: @pankajparkar I though `this` and `$ scope` was the same thing. I'll try this asap.

Comment: let me know if its work or not?

Comment: It worked with `$scope.$parent.$parent.main.currentURL` ! I have no clue why I had to access it this way

Comment: because you used `ng-include` that tend you to do `$parent.$parent` which is correct AFAIK..extra $parent came because of `ng-include` which create a child scope..

Comment: Alright thank you mate. Could you post an answer so I can validate it ?

Comment: sure I will do it in 5 minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to access `mainCtrl` which was inside `loginCtrl` controller then you need use `$parent` to access parent controller scope.

But the thing is you are loading `loginCtrl` controller view using `ng-include` so your controller is loaded in the child scope of the `mainCtrl`, because `ng-include` create a child scope from current scope.

For that reason you need use `$parent.$parent` to access `mainCtrl` scope from `loginCtrl`

**Code**

```
function loginCtrl($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    console.log($scope.$parent.$parent); // this would contain mainCtrl
}
```

Better approach would be to use controllerAs syntax or follow dot rule while defining objects so that prototypal inheritance gets followed.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helps ypu..Thanks :)